# Proving Saalschutz Theorem

Tags: hypergeometric-function

I saw this in a pdf, and I'm wondering

> **Questions:**
>
> 1. How do you prove Saalschutz Theorem:
>
> $$_3F_2\left[\begin{array}{c,c}-x,-y,-z\\n+1,-x-y-z-n\end{array}\right]=\dfrac {\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+y+n+1)\Gamma(y+z+n+1)\Gamma(z+x+n+1)}{\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)\Gamma(z+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+n+1)}\tag{1}$$

I'm somewhat relatively new to Hypergeometrical Series. I understand that the general Hypergeometrical series takes the form$$_pF_q\left[\begin{array}{c,c}\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\ldots,\alpha_p\\\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots,\beta_q\end{array};x\right]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {(\alpha_1)_k(\alpha_2)_k\ldots(\alpha_p)_k}{(\beta_1)_k(\beta_2)_k\ldots(\beta_q)_k}\dfrac {x^k}{k!}\tag{2}$$
So therefore, by $(2)$, we should have$$_3F_2\left[\begin{array}{c,c}-x,-y,-z\\n+1,-x-y-z-n\end{array}\right]=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\dfrac {(-x)_k(-y)_k(-z)_k}{(n+1)_k(-x-y-z-n)_k}\tag{3}$$
However, I'm not sure how to manipulate the RHS of $(3)$ to get the RHS of $(1)$.

**EDIT:** Since $(a)_k=\Gamma(a+k)/\Gamma(a)$, the RHS of $(3)$ becomes$$\dfrac {(-x)_k(-y)_k(-z)_k}{(n+1)_k(-x-y-z-n)_k}=\dfrac {\Gamma(k-y)\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(k-x)\Gamma(-x-y-z-n)\Gamma)k-z)}{\Gamma(n+k+1)\Gamma(-x)\Gamma(-y)\Gamma(-z)\Gamma(-x-y-z-n+k)}$$Now, I need to figure out how$$\Gamma(k-y)\Gamma(k-x)\Gamma(k-z)\Gamma(-x-y-z-n)=\Gamma(x+y+n+1)\Gamma(y+z+n+1)\Gamma(x+z+n+1)$$$$\Gamma(n+k+1)\Gamma(-x)\Gamma(-y)\Gamma(-z)\Gamma(-x-y-z-n+k)=\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)\Gamma(z+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+n+1)$$

---

> ***Extra:*** I also believe that using the same general approach, we can prove$$\begin{align*} & _7F_6\left[\begin{array}{c,c}n,\frac 12n+1,-x,-y,-z,-u,x+y+z+u+2n+1\\\frac 12n,x+n+1,y+n+1,z+n+1,u+n+1,-x-y-z-u-n\end{array}\right]\\ & =\dfrac {\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)\Gamma(z+n+1)\Gamma(u+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+n+1)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+y+n+1)\Gamma(y+z+n+1)\Gamma(x+u+n+1)\Gamma(z+u+n+1)}\\ & \times\dfrac {\Gamma(y+z+u+n+1)\Gamma(x+u+z+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+u+n+1)}{\Gamma(x+z+n+1)\Gamma(y+u+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+u+n+1)}\end{align*}\tag{4}$$

Comment: i have no idea about a direct proof, but i am sure that an appropriate  Wilf-Zeilberger pair can be found.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilf%E2%80%93Zeilberger_pair

Comment: http://ac.els-cdn.com/0097316585900263/1-s2.0-0097316585900263-main.pdf?_tid=ca1e5248-f86e-11e6-a350-00000aacb35e&acdnat=1487706720_6bba5d6d246e048c6cd59a72d717eea0

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **Prove**$$_3F_2\left[\begin{array}{c,c}-x,-y,-z\\n+1,-x-y-z-n\end{array}\right]=\dfrac {\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma(x+y+n+1)\Gamma(y+z+n+1)\Gamma(z+x+n+1)}{\Gamma(x+n+1)\Gamma(y+n+1)\Gamma(z+n+1)\Gamma(x+y+z+n+1)}$$

---

*Proof:* Begin with the identity$$(1-z)^{a+b-c}\space_2F_1(a,b;c;z)=_2F_1(c-a,b-a;c;z)\tag1$$This can be easily proven by setting both solutions of the second order linear differential equation$$(z-z^2)\frac {d^2y}{dz^2}+\bigr\{c-(a+b+1)z\bigr\}\frac {dy}{dx}-aby=0$$equal to each other, and changing the dependent variables. Starting with $(1)$, rewrite it as a summation, and then find the coefficient of $z^n$.$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty\frac {(a+b-c)_k}{k!}(-z)^k\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac {(a)_r(b)_r}{(c)_r}\frac {z^r}{r!}=\sum\limits_{l=0}^{\infty}\frac {(c-a)_l(b-a)_l}{(c)_l}\frac {z^l}{l!}\tag2$$The coefficient of $z^n$ of $(2)$ is therefore$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac {(a)_r(b)_r(c-a-b)_{n-r}}{(n-r)!(c)_rr!}=\frac {(c-a)_n(b-a)_n}{(c)_nn!}\tag3$$And from $(3)$, it follows that the left-hand side is equal to$$\sum\limits_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac {(a)_r(b)_r}{(c)_r}\frac {(c-a-b)_n(-n)_r}{(1+a+b-c-n)_rn!}=_3F_2\left[\begin{array}{c c}a,b,-n\\c,1+a+b-c-n\end{array}\right]\frac 1{n!(c-a-b)_n}$$Equating to the right-hand side of $(3)$, and simplifying, we get the identity$$_3F_2\left[\begin{array}{c c}a,b,-n\\c,1+a+b-c-n\end{array}\right]=\frac {\Gamma(c)\Gamma(c-a-b)\Gamma(n-a+b)\Gamma(n-a+c)}{\Gamma(b-a)\Gamma(c-a)\Gamma(c+n)\Gamma(n+c-a-b)}\tag4$$Replacing $a=-x,b=-y,n=z,$ and $c$ with $n+1$, we deduce **Saalschutz's theorem**.

Comment: nice alternative way (+1), although I am a bit perplex about whether the convergency criteria for $F$ are preserved .

Answer (score 6):

The development of the Saalschütz's identity that I know proceeds along the following path.

Start with the known identity about the sum of the product of three binomials:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
  F(m,n,r,s)\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers}\,m,n} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\   k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + r - s \\   n - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r + k \\   m + n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\begin{subarray}{l} 
  \left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right) \\ 
  \left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m + n} \right) 
\end{subarray}}  {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\   k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + r - s \\   n - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\   m + n - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  k \\   j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\begin{subarray}{l} 
  \left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;k\,\left( { \leqslant \,n} \right) \\ 
  \left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m + n} \right) 
\end{subarray}}  {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\   j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s - j \\   k - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + r - s \\   n - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\   m + n - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m + n} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\   j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + m - j \\   n - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\   m + n - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m + n} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\   j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + m - j \\   m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\   m + n - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \leqslant } \right)\;j\,\left( { \leqslant \,m + n} \right)} {\left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\   j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\   m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r - m \\   n - j \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)}  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\   m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  s \\   n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \tag{1}
} $$
where the steps are:
 - inverse convolution on last b.;
 - trinomial revision on 1st and 4th b.;
 - convolution in $k$ on 2nd and 3rd b.;
 - symmetry on 2nd b.;
 - trinomial revision on 2nd and 3rd b.;
 - convolution in $j$ on 1st and 3rd b.

Then consider that the addenda in the sum are
$$
\begin{gathered}
  t_{\,k}  = \left( \begin{gathered}
  m - r + s \\ 
  k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  n + r - s \\ 
  n - k \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r + k \\ 
  m + n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( {m - r + s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } }}
{{k!}}\frac{{\left( {n + r - s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - k\,} } }}
{{\left( {n - k} \right)!}}\frac{{\left( {r + k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m + n\,} } }}
{{\left( {m + n} \right)!}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
where $x^{\,\underline {\,k\,} }$ indicates the falling factorial. 
The value of the initial term is
$$
t_{\,0}  = \frac{{\left( {n + r - s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n\,} } }}
{{n!}}\frac{{r^{\,\underline {\,m + n\,} } }}
{{\left( {m + n} \right)!}} = \left( \begin{gathered}
  n + r - s \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\ 
  m + n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)
$$
and the ratio of consecutive terms is a rational function in $k$
$$
\begin{gathered}
  \frac{{t_{\,k + 1} }}
{{t_{\,k} }} = \frac{{\left( {m - r + s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k + 1\,} } \left( {n + r - s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - k - 1\,} } \left( {r + k + 1} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m + n\,} } }}
{{\left( {m - r + s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,k\,} } \left( {n + r - s} \right)^{\,\underline {\,n - k\,} } \left( {r + k} \right)^{\,\underline {\,m + n\,} } }}\frac{{k!\left( {n - k} \right)!\left( {m + n} \right)!}}
{{\left( {k + 1} \right)!\left( {n - k - 1} \right)!\left( {m + n} \right)!}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( {m - r + s - k} \right)\left( {r + k + 1} \right)}}
{{\left( {r - s + 1 + k} \right)\left( {r + k - m - n + 1} \right)}}\frac{{\left( {n - k} \right)}}
{{\left( {k + 1} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( {r - m - s + k} \right)\left( {r + 1 + k} \right)\left( { - n + k} \right)}}
{{\left( {r - s + 1 + k} \right)\left( {r - m - n + 1 + k} \right)\left( {1 + k} \right)}} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
so that we can write
$$
\begin{gathered}
  F(m,n,r,s) = t_0 \;{}_3F_2 \left[ {\left. \begin{gathered}
  r + 1,\;r - m - s,\; - n \hfill \\
  r - s + 1,\;r - m - n + 1\; \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right|\;1} \right] =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  n + r - s \\ 
  n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\ 
  m + n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;{}_3F_2 \left[ {\left. \begin{gathered}
  r + 1,\;r - m - s,\; - n \hfill \\
  r - s + 1,\;r - m - n + 1\; \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right|\;1} \right] \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered} 
$$
that is, changing $n$ to $q$ so not to get confused with your notation:
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
  {}_3F_2 \left[ {\left. \begin{gathered}
  r + 1,\;r - m - s,\; - q \hfill \\
  r - s + 1,\;r - m - q + 1\; \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right|\;1} \right]\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers}\,m,q} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
  s \\ 
  q \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\ 
  m \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;\mathop /\limits_{} \;\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  q + r - s \\ 
  q \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
  r \\ 
  m + q \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {s + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - s + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - m - q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {m + q + 1} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( {s - q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - m + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {m + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {q + r - s + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r + 1} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\Gamma \left( {s + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - s + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - m - q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {m + q + 1} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( {s - q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - s + q + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {r - m + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( {m + 1} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{s^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } \left( {r - s} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,q\,} } }}
{{\left( {r - m} \right)^{\,\underline {\,q\,} } m^{\,\underline {\, - q\,} } }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}   \tag{2}
} $$
which you can compare with your notation ( not forgetting the final $1/k!$ term) to get
$$
\left\{ \begin{gathered}
  q = z \hfill \\
  m = y + n \hfill \\
  r =  - x - 1 \hfill \\
  s =  - x - 1 - n \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right.
$$
and finally 
$$ \bbox[lightyellow] {
\begin{gathered}
  {}_3F_2 \left[ {\left. \begin{gathered}
   - x,\; - y,\; - z \hfill \\
  n + 1,\; - x - y - z - n\; \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right|\;1} \right]\quad \left| {\;0 \leqslant \text{integers}\,z,\left( {y + n} \right)} \right.\quad  =  \hfill \\
   = \left( \begin{gathered}
   - x - 1 - n \\ 
  z \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
   - x - 1 \\ 
  y + n \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\;\mathop /\limits_{} \;\left( {\left( \begin{gathered}
  z + n \\ 
  z \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)\left( \begin{gathered}
   - x - 1 \\ 
  y + n + z \\ 
\end{gathered}  \right)} \right) =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\Gamma \left( { - x - n} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( { - x - y - n - z} \right)\Gamma \left( {y + n + z + 1} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( { - x - n - z} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 1 + z} \right)\Gamma \left( { - x - y - n} \right)\Gamma \left( {y + n + 1} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( { - x - 1 - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,z\,} } \,n^{\,\underline {\, - \,\,z\,} } }}
{{\left( { - x - 1 - n - y} \right)^{\,\underline {\,z\,} } \;\left( {n + y} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,z\,} } }} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\Gamma \left( { - x - n} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( { - x - y - n - z} \right)\Gamma \left( {y + n + z + 1} \right)}}
{{\Gamma \left( { - x - y - n} \right)\Gamma \left( {y + n + 1} \right)\Gamma \left( { - x - n - z} \right)\Gamma \left( {n + 1 + z} \right)}} =  \hfill \\
   = \frac{{\left( { - x - 1 - n} \right)^{\,\underline {\,y\,} } \,n^{\,\underline {\, - \,\,y\,} } }}
{{\left( { - x - 1 - n - z} \right)^{\,\underline {\,y\,} } \;\left( {n + z} \right)^{\,\underline {\, - \,y\,} } }} \hfill \\ 
\end{gathered}   \tag{3}
} $$

*----   Addendum -------*

Identity (1) is famous because it is one of the very few involving the product of more than two binomials,
  and can be found in good collections of binomial identities .

A hint on how it could be related to binomial expansion can be got from considering
how it works for the last step, i.e.
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,r} \left( {1 + y} \right)^{\,s}  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,m} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,n} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 r \\ 
 m \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 s \\ 
 n \\ 
 \end{array} \right)x^{\,m} y^{\,n} } }  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,m} {\;\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,n} {\sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\;j\,\left( { \le \,n} \right)} {\left( \begin{array}{c}
 m - r + s \\ 
 j \\ 
 \end{array} \right)\left( \begin{array}{c}
 r - m \\ 
 n - j \\ 
 \end{array} \right)z^{\,j} y^{\,n} \left( \begin{array}{c}
 r \\ 
 m \\ 
 \end{array} \right)x^{\,m} } } }  =  \\ 
  = \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,m} {\;\left( {1 + yz} \right)^{\,m - r + s} \left( {1 + y} \right)^{\,r - m} \left( \begin{array}{c}
 r \\ 
 m \\ 
 \end{array} \right)x^{\,m} }  =  \\ 
  = \left( {1 + yz} \right)^s \sum\limits_{\left( {0\, \le } \right)\,m} {\left( {\frac{{1 + y}}{{1 + yz}}} \right)^{\,r - m} \left( \begin{array}{c}
 r \\ 
 m \\ 
 \end{array} \right)x^{\,m} }  =  \\ 
  = \left( {1 + yz} \right)^s \left( {\frac{{1 + y}}{{1 + yz}} + x} \right)^r  \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
and then put $z=1$.

*Note:*  the bounds put in brackets are to indicate that, from an algebraic point of view, they are superfluous because inherent to the binomial coeff. (which is null outside them); this is important to carry on in order to correctly apply the convolution.

A combinatorial proof can be found [in this interesting paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X75900011)

Comment: How do you derive the identity for the three binomials you mentioned at the beginning of your answer? Is there a way to relate that to the coefficient of $x^n$ in some sort of binomial identity?

Comment: @FrankW.: I put and Addendum to the answer , in reply to your request.

Comment: @FrankW.: a) well yes, $0 \le n,m$ was a shortcut to indicate the sum over $m$ and $n$, both non-negative b) I changed  the symbology, and also amended for a typo.  Hope now it is clear

Comment: If I may, how are you getting the second line with the three separate sums? I see that the $\binom rm$ is preserved, but I’m not understanding where the extra $z$ factor comes in. Could you elaborate that a bit for me? Also doesn’t the sum have to be infinite for it to fit the hypergeometric function? Thanks.

Comment: I hope you don’t mind, I added a question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2816488/proving-sum-limits-k-0n-binom-m-rsk-binom-nr-sn-k-binom-rkmn. Perhaps you can give me a more detailed answer explaining each step? I’m having difficulty understanding.

Comment: @FrankW.: a) you can introduce $\cdot (z=1)^j$ anywhere in a sum (you put 1, change to z, make the sum, change to 1 at the end, if that does not alter convergence) b) a hypergeometric sum can be actually limited, if one of the factors in the numerator becomes $0$ after a certain $n$. c) ok, let's switch to your new post.