# Proving $\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom {m-r+s}k\binom {n+r-s}{n-k}\binom {r+k}{m+n}=\binom rm\binom sn$

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

> **Question:** How do you show the following equality holds using binomials$$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\binom {m-r+s}k\binom {r+k}{m+n}\binom {n+r-s}{n-k}=\binom rm\binom sn$$

I would like to prove the identity using some sort of binomial identity. The right-hand side is the coefficient of $x^m$ and $y^n$ in$$\begin{align*}a_{m,n} & =\left[x^m\right]\left[y^n\right](1+x)^r(1+y)^s\\ & =\binom rm\binom sn\end{align*}$$

However, I don’t see how the left-hand side can be proven using the binomials. Using the generalized binomial theorem, we get the right-hand side as

$$\begin{align*}(1+x)^r(1+y)^s & =\sum\limits_{k\geq0}\sum\limits_{l\geq0}\binom rk\binom slx^ky^l\end{align*}$$However, what do I do from here?

Comment: Not that it entirely corresponds to your question, but this may be of a little help, away the use of Binomial Theorem: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2381429/proving-this-infinite-sum-of-a-product-of-three-binomials-sum-limits-s-bino?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With OP asking for formal power series in the evaluation of

$$\sum_{k\ge 0} {m-r+s\choose k} {r+k\choose m+n}
{n+r-s\choose n-k}$$

we write

$$[z^n] (1+z)^{n+r-s}  [w^{m+n}] (1+w)^r
\sum_{k\ge 0} {m-r+s\choose k}
z^k (1+w)^k
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{n+r-s}  [w^{m+n}] (1+w)^r
(1+z+zw)^{m-r+s}
\\ = [z^n] (1+z)^{n+r-s}  [w^{m+n}] (1+w)^r
\sum_{q=0}^{m-r+s} {m-r+s\choose q}
(1+z)^{m-r+s-q} z^q w^q
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{m-r+s} {m-r+s\choose q}
{m+n-q\choose n-q} {r\choose m+n-q}.$$

Note that

$${m+n-q\choose n-q} {r\choose m+n-q}
= \frac{r!}{(n-q)! \times m! \times (r+q-m-n)!}
\\ = {r\choose m} {r-m\choose n-q}.$$

We thus have

$${r\choose m}
\sum_{q=0}^{m-r+s} {m-r+s\choose q} {r-m\choose n-q}
\\ = {r\choose m} [z^n] (1+z)^{r-m}
\sum_{q=0}^{m-r+s} {m-r+s\choose q} z^q
\\ = {r\choose m} [z^n] (1+z)^{r-m} (1+z)^{m-r+s}
= {r\choose m} {s\choose n}.$$

This is the claim.

Comment: Sorry for the necro-post, but is there a collection of these infinite binomial sums? I'm trying to generate larger sums that are similar as the one in the question using the same methodology.

Comment: There is this list of [Egorychev method / method of coefficients](http://pnp.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/iadm/Riedel/egorychev.html) applications. It is not limited to binomial coefficients.

Comment: I'm mainly looking for identities similar to the ones in the question though: infinite sum, composed of binomials, closed form is a product of binomials. I'm trying to derive more identities using the same process you've demonstrated in your answer, but every time I try, it ends up simplifying to the sum in the question; was wondering if there were others

Comment: Another list is H. W. Gould's *Combinatorial identities.*

Answer (score 5):

$$
\begin{align}
&\sum_{k=0}^\infty\binom{m-r+s}{k}\binom{r+k}{m+n}\binom{n+r-s}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m-r+s}{k}\binom{k}{j}\binom{r}{m+n-j}\binom{n+r-s}{n-k}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m-r+s}{j}\binom{m-r+s-j}{k-j}\binom{r}{m+n-j}\binom{n+r-s}{n-k}\tag2\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m-r+s}{j}\binom{m+n-j}{n-j}\binom{r}{m+n-j}\tag3\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m-r+s}{j}\binom{m+n-j}{m}\binom{r}{m+n-j}\tag4\\
&=\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{m-r+s}{j}\binom{r-m}{n-j}\binom{r}{m}\tag5\\
&=\binom{s}{n}\binom{r}{m}\tag6
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: [Vandermonde's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity) applied to the sum in $j$
$(2)$: $\binom{m-r+s}{k}\binom{k}{j}=\binom{m-r+s}{j}\binom{m-r+s-j}{k-j}$
$(3)$: Vandermonde's Identity applied to the sum in $k$
$(4)$: $\binom{m+n-j}{n-j}=\binom{m+n-j}{m}$
$(5)$: $\binom{m+n-j}{m}\binom{r}{m+n-j}=\binom{r-m}{n-j}\binom{r}{m}$
$(6)$: Vandermonde's Identity applied to the sum in $j$

Comment: right: that is in line with the  explanation I gave in previous answer [to this related post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155025)

Comment: @robjohn, do you mind checking this binomial identity, Thank you so much!! https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3278355/a-binomial-identity-conjecture-numerically-true-very-hard-to-prove

Answer (score 1):

**Premise**

Let's first see which are the  series corresponding to the basic manipulations involved in the algebraic demonstration of the identity in question.

*1) Convolution*
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {1 + yx} \right)^{\,r} \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,s}  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {
 \left( \matrix{ r \cr   j \cr}  \right)\,\left( \matrix{  s \cr  k \cr}  \right)x^{\,j} y^{\,j} \;x^{\,k} }    }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j}   {
 \left( \matrix{ r \cr   j \cr}  \right)\,\left( \matrix{  s \cr   k + j - j \cr}  \right)x^{\,j + k} y^{\,j} }   }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,l} {\left( {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {
 \left( \matrix{ r \cr   j \cr}  \right)\,\left( \matrix{  s \cr  l - j \cr}  \right)y^{\,j} } } \right)x^{\,l}    }
   \cr} 
$$
in which, of course, one can put $x$ and/or $y$ to $1$, or other value.

*2) Trinomial Revision*

Trinomial Revision does not have a single z-Transform for the repeated index, but the double one is quite simple
$$
\eqalign{
  & \left( {1 + y\left( {1 + x} \right)} \right)^{\,r}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)y^{\,k} \left( {1 + x} \right)^{\,k} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m\,\left( { \le \,k} \right)} {\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  k \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  k \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)y^{\,k} x^{\,m} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \left( {1 + y + yx} \right)^{\,r}  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)\left( {yx} \right)^{\,m} \left( {1 + y} \right)^{\,r - m} }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,j} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r - m \cr 
  j \cr}  \right)y^{\,m} y^{\,j} x^{\,m} } }  =   \cr 
  &  = \sum\limits_{m\, \le \,m + j} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r - m \cr 
  \left( {m + j} \right) - m \cr}  \right)y^{\,\left( {m + j} \right)} x^{\,m} } }  = \sum\limits_{0\, \le \,\left( {m\, \le } \right)\,k} {\sum\limits_{0\, \le \,m} {\left( \matrix{
  r \cr 
  m \cr}  \right)\left( \matrix{
  r - m \cr 
  k - m \cr}  \right)y^{\,k} x^{\,m} } }  \cr} 
$$

**Your Request**

Considering the requirement of your post, if we take the expansion already given
in [the related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2155025), which is equivalent to that given above by *robjohn*,
and attempt to go backwards, we will realize that we are going into a complicated formal series involving
some five or six variables, which does not seem to be much of interest.
That's mainly due to the Trinomial Revision asking for a double sum.

The first step in such a backward route was already given in the answer to the cited related post.

Comment: Sorry, I'm still kind of confused. Just give me some time; still processing everything! :)